# I want to create a localstorage inside a .subscribe but it creates the localstorage after all the functions

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to check in a form is the user exists in a MySQL Database with angular.
I am creating a localstorage item inside a .subscribe so if the user exists it creates a localstorage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("exist","true");
```

but if it doesn't exist makes this:

```
localStorage.setItem("exist","false");
```

After the function I check if it is true or false, but it is null, because .subscribe makes it after all the functions. So if I check a 2nd time it makes the localstorage item correctly.

```
this.userService.getAutor(id)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => { // Successins
      localStorage.setItem("exist","true");
    },
    (error) => { // error
      localStorage.setItem("exist","false");
    }
  );
}
```

This is where I am calling the function

```
  this.usuarioExiste(this.dniAutor);

      if(localStorage.getItem('existe') == 'false'){
        var expReg = /^(\d{8})([A-Z])$/;

        if(expReg.test(this.dniAutor)){

          this.userService.crearAutor(JSONform)
          .subscribe(

            (data) => { // Success
              console.log("¡Bien HECHO!");
            }
          );
          alert("Autor añadido correctamente");
        }
else{
  alert("Dni mal introducido")
}
```

Comment: Does `userService.getAutor` definitely error when the user doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, because it's a get request, so if you request a get to a id that doesn't exists it returns false

Comment: But what status code does the http response return?

Comment: I don't really know, I only want to return or create a var when .subscribe finishes, but it doesn't do it unitl later on.

Comment: As you said, `.subscribe` makes it after all the functions. Because, `.getAutor` returns back an observable and it's asynchronose. You have add your check logic inside the subscribe.

Comment: Pls post some more code and the XHR response.

Comment: You need to understand what your http requests and responses are if you are going to handle them correctly. Try `console.log(data)` inside the subscribe method, and inspect your network tab in dev tools when making an invalid request.

Comment: Adding more code in a moment. Thank you all!

Comment: Please can you link the method with which you check your local storage value. As suggested above you are likely running into a problem with the asynchronous nature of your subscription. You could test this by placing the call to this function directly after you save the value to local storage (the line after - within the subscription)

Comment: When I am Checking the value of the local storage the first time it doesn't work because the local storage gets the value the second time

Comment: I know it's very dumb and wrong but I can get all the id of the authors and when I am checking if an author exists check it in the array. It's wrong but it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the function I check if it is true or false, but it is null

#### Wrong way

```
this.userService.getAutor(id)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => { // Successins
      localStorage.setItem('existe',"true"); // <-- called after functionCheckIfTrueOrFalse, NO DATA in storage yet
    },
    (error) => { // error
      localStorage.setItem('existe',"false"); // <-- called after functionCheckIfTrueOrFalse, NO DATA in storage yet
    }
  );
}
functionCheckIfTrueOrFalse() // <- is called before any localStorage.setItem()
```

#### Correct way

```
this.userService.getAutor(id)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => { // Successins
      localStorage.setItem('existe',"true");
      functionCheckIfTrueOrFalse() // <- localStorage HAS the data
    },
    (error) => { // error
      localStorage.setItem('existe',"false");
      functionCheckIfTrueOrFalse() // <- localStorage HAS the data
    }
  );
}
```

### Knowledge

If you want to spend time and understand how it works under the hood, you can check [this article](https://blog.strongbrew.io/what-are-schedulers-in-rxjs/).

In nutshell JavaScript handles async treads differently:

[image]

You get `null` because you are reading data from the sync **Queue** before you get data from the **Async** tread.

Comment: O wow thanks!! I am currently learning typeScript and Java and this is very usefull! Checking if it works

Comment: Note that "Java" and "JavaScript" are different ones ;). If you are new to JS and TS, those are nice places to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript, https://www.typescriptlang.org/. Good luck!

Comment: you can call `functionCheckIfTrueOrFalse()` in complete callback as well

Answer (score 0):

As Kurt mentioned, my answer needs an explanation.

So I'll do my best below:

You have to check first if the data is available when you are in the subscribe method due to the asynchronous nature of the call. And only then you access the local storage as you intend.

Note: You can also use the filter operator like so `filter(data => data)` to skip the if condition but only if you're not interested to access the local storage if the data doesn't exist.

```
 this.userService.getAutor(id).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        localStorage.setItem('existe', 'true');
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('existe', 'false');
      }
    });
```

Comment: I think an explanation of why you think this might work would help OP here

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked!

I used the suggestion of 0leg and it worked!

```
this.userService.getAutor(id).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        localStorage.setItem('existe', 'true');
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('existe', 'false');
      }
    });

Many thanks to all!

Have a nice day!
```